# jquery mobile custom icons not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am working with jquery mobile 1.4.5 and jquery 1.9.1 and can not seem to get the custom icons working.  Gray empty circles appear instead of the icon.  I have found several SO questions regarding this but none of them solved my problem.  I have taking the example right from the jquery website [Here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/#&ui-state=dialog)

Here is my jsfiddle:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/at9t5kzc/1/)

I have also tried both methods of using a the ui-icon-class as well as the data-icon="myicon" attribute.  What am I missing?

HTML:

```
 <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-myicon">myicon</button>
 <button data-icon="myicon" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left">myicon</button>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.ui-icon-myicon:after {
 background-image: url("http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2219/dot_pictograms/128/drink_bar_cocktails.png"); 
 background-size: 18px 18px;
d}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/at9t5kzc/2/

Comment: Well, you got it working but I don't know why.  the code is the same.  I even checked the order of how I load the jqm.css, jqm.js, and jquery.js.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have some bad characters in your CSS text. In your fiddle, try just backspacing from background-image and background-size to the start of the line (i.e. remove all indenting).

Comment: Thanks I had that corrected in the question but didn't update the fiddle.  I have now updated the fiddle and it still does not work. any ideas? this is driving me crazy.  It has to be something stupid.

Comment: here is your fiddle with just the extra CSS and indenting removed: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/at9t5kzc/4/

Comment: OMG. I just found it right before you.  You were correct. It was some hidden character that somehow got in the css that was corrupting the whole thing.  What a waste of a morning.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the class you are targeting. If you change the class to `.ui-btn-icon-left` then it works.

```
.ui-btn-icon-left:after {
  background-image: url("http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2219/dot_pictograms/128/drink_bar_cocktails.png");
  background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense and is not at all what the docs say.  the .ui-btn-icon-left class is just from positioning in the button.

Comment: just working with the fiddle provided, that's how I was able to get it to work. I believe @ezanker got it right